# C++ : How to programmatically define template types in runtime?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a requirement where there's a enum and there are template functions defined for all the possible enum combinations upto length l.

Say the enum is

```
Enum typenum {A, B, C}
```

And all these template functions are defined and available at runtime (i.e, compiler creates these functions at the compile time)

```
Alpha<A>::f()
Alpha<B>::f()
Alpha<C>::f()
Alpha<A,A>::f()
Alpha<A,B>::f()
Alpha<A,C>::f()
Alpha<B,A>::f()
Alpha<B,B>::f()
Alpha<B,C>::f()
Alpha<C,A>::f()
Alpha<C,B>::f()
Alpha<C,C>::f()
and combination of 3 enums, 4 enums...
```

Now I've to choose the right function as per an input vector

```
void f(vector<enum> eVec){
    Alpha::f<eVec[0], eVec[1],... eVec[eVec.size() - 1]>() // <-------
```

How do I do this? One way to do this would be to define for every size. Eg:

```
if(eVec.size() == 1)
   Alpha<eVec[0]>::f()
else if(eVec.size() == 2)
   Alpha<eVec[0], eVec[1]>::f()
```

This won't scale though. Is there any elegant, scalable way of doing this.

Comment: Are you sure templates are the correct approach here? This just seems to be needlessly complicated

Comment: Yeah, it's a part of very complicated code that's really tough to explain here. I tried to condense it to the bare minimum.

Comment: And the language is? C++?

Comment: Yes, it is C++.

Comment: C++11, C++14 or C++17? Another question: we can imagine a superior limit for the length of the vector? Say 10 for an example?

Comment: C++11. Yes, we can assume some fixed upper length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I've realized that this approach won't work. Because when we write something like

```
Alpha<eVec[0]>::f()
```

Compiler throws an error - " error: expression must have a constant value"

So the only alternative left is

```
if(eVec.size() == 1){
    switch(eVec[0]){
        case A:
            Alpha<A>::f()
.....
```

This is because the compiler needs to know all possible parameter types using which templates would be called during compile time.

Comment: Final code won't work also… for the same reason that original code won't… Template is not the solution if values are not compile-time constants and it does not make much sense to use the switch approach...

Comment: Yeah, actually. I'm removing the final code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

> And all these template functions are defined and available at runtime (i.e, compiler creates these functions at the compile time)

Are you sure it's a good idea?
Because, if you want select run-time template values, you have to implement, compile time, all possible `Alpha<typeNumsValues...>::f()` combinations.
That is impossible if you don't impose a length limit for the variadic list, but is very computationally expensive also when there is relatively low limit.

Anyway... suppose you have an enum as follows

```
enum typeEnum { A, B, C };
```

and variadic template `Alpha` class, with `typeEnum` template values and a  `static` method `f()` as follows

```
template <typeEnum ...>
struct Alpha
 { static void f () { /* do something */ } };
```

your `f()` can call a variadic `f_helper()`

```
void f (std::vector<typeEnum> const & eVec)
 { f_helper<>(eVec, 0u); }
```

realized as follows

```
template <typeEnum ...>
void f_helper (std::vector<typeEnum> const &, ...)
 { }

template <typeEnum ... Tes>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Tes) < 6u)>::type
    f_helper (std::vector<typeEnum> const & eVec, std::size_t index)
 {
   if ( index < eVec.size() )
      switch ( eVec[index++] )
       {
         case A: f_helper<Tes..., A>(eVec, index); break;
         case B: f_helper<Tes..., B>(eVec, index); break;
         case C: f_helper<Tes..., C>(eVec, index); break;
       }
   else
      Alpha<Tes...>::f();
 }
```

Observe that I've posed a very low limit (5, `sizeof...(Tes) < 6u`) to the length of the variadic list because the number of developed `Alpha` grows exponentially.

Also observe that I've added a do-nothing version of `f_helper()`; it's necessary because the less-than-6-length recursively call `f_helper()`, can call it with a variadic list of 6 enums that must be managed in some way.

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <vector>    

enum typeEnum { A, B, C };

template <typeEnum ...>
struct Alpha
 { static void f () { } };

template <typeEnum ...>
void f_helper (std::vector<typeEnum> const &, ...)
 { }

template <typeEnum ... Tes>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof...(Tes) < 6u)>::type
    f_helper (std::vector<typeEnum> const & eVec, std::size_t index)
 {
   if ( index < eVec.size() )
      switch ( eVec[index++] )
       {
         case A: f_helper<Tes..., A>(eVec, index); break;
         case B: f_helper<Tes..., B>(eVec, index); break;
         case C: f_helper<Tes..., C>(eVec, index); break;
       }
   else
      Alpha<Tes...>::f();
 }

void f (std::vector<typeEnum> const & eVec)
 { f_helper<>(eVec, 0u); }   

int main ()
 {
   f({A, B, C, A});
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want specific functions from runtime variable then use a `map` instead. Template is the wrong tool for the job as you have to write lot just to transform variable into constants.

Assuming that you `enum` have a default value `None` and that you have up to say 5 arguments, you can define a map like this:

```
enum MyEnum { None = 0, A, B, C, D... };
using MyKey = std::tuple<MyEnum, MyEnum, MyEnum, MyEnum, MyEnum>;
using MyFunction = std::function<void()>;
```

Then you have somewhere a map of function (a singleton)

```
std::map<MyKey, MyFunction> myMap;
```

A utility function could be helpful to create a key from a variable number of arguments:

```
MyKey MakeKey(MyEnum e1, MyEnum e2 = None, MyEnum e3 = None, MyEnum e4 = None, MyEnum e5 = None)
{
    return std::make_tuple(e1, e2, e3, e4, e5);
}

myMap.emplace(MakeKey(A, B), [](){ /* some code */ });

MyEnum AtOrDefault(const vector<enum> &eVec, int index)
{
    return index < eVec.size() ? eVec[index] : None;
}
```

Then assuming you want to call the appropriate function from a vector, you could do:

```
void f(const vector<enum> &eVec)
{
    if (eVec.size() > 5) throw some_exception;

    MyKey key = std::make_typle(
        AtOrDefault(eVec, 0), 
        AtOrDefault(eVec, 1), 
        AtOrDefault(eVec, 2), 
        AtOrDefault(eVec, 3), 
        AtOrDefault(eVec, 4));

    auto &fn = myMap[key];
    fn();
}
```

You could also use the idea of calculating a value assuming that you know the maximum number of elements in the enum. You could then create a CombinedEnumType:

```
enum CombinedEnumType : uint32_t { };
```

And defined a function

```
CombinedEnumType MakeCombinedEnumType(MyEnum e1, … MyEnum e5 = None) 
{
    const int MyEnumEcount = 5;
    MyEnum a[] = { e1, e2, e3, e4, e5 };

    uint32_t result = 0;
    for (auto & item : a) { result *= MyEnumEcount; result += item; }
    return static_cast<CombinedEnumType>(result);
}
```

**This code is just for ideas. In real production code, you have to use constants, proper variable names, validate that a function exist for a given combination…**